# jest doesn't wait beforeAll resolution to start tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs, es6-promise, frisby.js

**What I test**: An express server endpoints

**My goal**: automate API tests in a single script

**What I do**: I launch the express server in a NodeJS child process and would like to wait for it to be launched before the test suite is run (frisby.js endpoints testing)

**What isn't working as expected**: Test suite is launched before Promise resolution

I rely on the [`wait-on`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on) package which server polls and resolves once the resource(s) is/are available.

```
const awaitServer = async () => {
  await waitOn({
    resources: [`http://localhost:${PORT}`],
    interval: 1000,
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Server is running, launching test suite now!');
  });
};
```

This function is used in the startServer function:

```
const startServer = async () => {
  console.log(`Launching server http://localhost:${PORT} ...`);

  // npmRunScripts is a thin wrapper around child_process.exec to easily access node_modules/.bin like in package.json scripts
  await npmRunScripts(
    `cross-env PORT=${PORT} node -r ts-node/register -r dotenv/config src/index.ts dotenv_config_path=.env-tests`
  );

  await awaitServer();
}
```

And finally, I use this in something like

```
describe('Endpoints' () => {
  beforeAll(startTestServer);

  // describes and tests here ...
});
```

Anyway, when I launch jest the `'Server is running, launching test suite now!'` console.log never shows up and the test suite fails (as the server isn't running already). Why does jest starts testing as `awaitServer` obviously hasn't resolved yet?

The `npmRunScripts` function works fine as the test server is up and running a short while after the tests have failed. For this question's sake, here's how npmRunScripts resolves:

```
// From https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2016/03/mimicking-npm-script-in-node-js/
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { delimiter, join } = require('path');

const env = { ...process.env };
const binPath = join(__dirname, '../..', 'node_modules', '.bin');

env.PATH = `${binPath}${delimiter}${env.PATH}`;

/**
 * Executes a CLI command with `./node_modules/.bin` in the scope like you
 * would use in the `scripts` sections of a `package.json`
 * @param cmd The actual command
 */
const npmRunScripts = (cmd, resolveProcess = false) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof cmd !== 'string') {
      reject(
        new TypeError(
          `npmRunScripts Error: cmd is a "${typeof cmd}", "string" expected.`
        )
      );
      return;
    }

    if (cmd === '') {
      reject(
        new Error(`npmRunScripts Error: No command provided (cmd is empty).`)
      );
      return;
    }

    const subProcess = exec(
      cmd,
      { cwd: process.cwd(), env }
    );

    if (resolveProcess) {
      resolve(subProcess);
    } else {
      const cleanUp = () => {
        subProcess.stdout.removeAllListeners();
        subProcess.stderr.removeAllListeners();
      };

      subProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        resolve(data);
        cleanUp();
      });
      subProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        reject(data);
        cleanUp();
      });
    }
  });

module.exports = npmRunScripts;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution. After trying almost anything, I didn't realize jest had a timeout setup which defaults at 5 seconds. So I increased this timeout and the tests now wait for the server promise to resolve.

I simply added `jest.setTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000);` before the test suite.

Comment: What if in some cases my queries needs more time? I cant understand why I have to do that. Why jest simply does not wait for all my promises in `beforeAll()`

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it caused by the flaw of the `beforeAll` part. Make sure the `beforeAll` doesn't contain any uncaught exceptions, otherwise it will behaves that the testing started without waiting for `beforeAll` resolves.

Comment: spent too many hours debugging this same situation :'(

Comment: This was also happening to me. Saved me a lot of time. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

After much digging I found a reason for why my `beforeAll` didn't seem to be running before my tests. This might be obvious to some, but it wasn't to me.

If you have code in your `describe` outside an `it` or other `beforeX` or `afterY`, and that code is dependent on any `beforeX`, you'll run into this problem.

The problem is that code in your `describe` is run before any `beforeX`. Therefore, that code won't have access to the dependencies that are resolved in any `beforeX`.

For example:

```js
describe('Outer describe', () => {
    let server;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        // Set up the server before all tests...
        server = await setupServer();
    });

    describe('Inner describe', () => {
        // The below line is run before the above beforeAll, so server doesn't exist here yet!
        const queue = server.getQueue(); // Error! server.getQueue is not a function
        it('Should use the queue', () => {
            queue.getMessage(); // Test fails due to error above
        });
    });
});
```

To me this seems unexpected, considering that code is run in the `describe` callback, so my impression was that that callback would be run after all `beforeX` outside the current `describe`.

It also seems this behavior won't be changed any time soon: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4097

Comment: I don't like this approach anyways. Tests should be isolated and therefore, avoid this kind of setup in a `beforeAll` implementation.

Comment: This just bit me too.  I refactored two 'it' blocks to factor out some common setup, and spent a day beating my head against why my tests were busted.

Comment: In my case I just had to remove `describe` altogether, not a big deal.

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of jest (at least >1.3.1) you can pass a `done` function to your `beforeAll` function and call it after everything is done:

```js
beforeAll(async (done) => {
  await myAsyncFunc();
  done();
})
it("Some test", async () => {
  // Runs after beforeAll
})
```

More discussions here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1256

Comment: This is handy! Thank you.

Comment: Not in version 27.